# Polyline only renders completely after resizing the window

Tags: c++, opengl

I am making a 3d project in OpenGL which contain a ground (drawn as line loops). The issue I have is when the project starts only a single line is drawn as shown in the next image:

[image]

When I resize or maximize the window then the actual ground gets displayed like this:

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this issue? I'm a beginner in OpenGL programming.

Here is the code :

```
void drawHook(void);
void timer(int);
void drawFlorr();
float L = 100;

const int screenWidth = 1000;      // width of screen window in pixels 
const int screenHeight = 1000;     // height of screen window in pixels
float ww = 800;
float wh = 800;
float f = 520, n = 10.0;
static GLdouble ort1[] = { -200, 200, -33, 140 };
static GLdouble viewer[] = { 525, 25, -180 };
static GLdouble objec[] = { 525.0, 25, -350 };
float x, y = 0.0, z, z1;
float xmax = screenWidth - 200.0;
float zmax = screenWidth - 200.0;
float xmin, zmin;
float step = 5.0;

float fov = 80;

 void myInit(void)
 {
        glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);       // background color is white

    glPointSize(2.0);                 // a 'dot' is 2 by 2 pixels
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);       
    glLoadIdentity();
     gluOrtho2D(0.0, screenWidth, 0.0, screenHeight);//dino window
     glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

}

void myDisplay(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    gluLookAt(viewer[0], viewer[1], viewer[2], objec[0], objec[1], objec[2], 0, 1, 0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(fov, 1.333, n, f);
    glPointSize(2.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    drawFlorr();


    glutSwapBuffers();


}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB); // set display mode
    glutInitWindowSize(screenWidth, screenHeight); // set window size
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10); // set window position on screen
    glutCreateWindow("Dino Line Drawing"); // open the screen window
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);     // register redraw function
    myInit();            
    //glutTimerFunc(1,timer,1);
    glutMainLoop();              // go into a perpetual loop
    return 1;
}
void drawFlorr()
{

    xmin = -100;
    zmin = -100;

    for (x = xmin; x < xmax; x += step)
    {
        for (z = zmin; z < zmax; z += step)
        {
            z1 = -z;

            glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

            glVertex3f(x, y, z1);
            glVertex3f(x, y, z1-step+1.0);
            glVertex3f(x + step - 1.0, y, z1 - step + 1.0);
            glVertex3f(x+step-1.0, y, z1);

            glEnd();


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is broken in many ways:

1. Your `myDisplay` function uses whatever the current matrix mode is to set the view matrix on.
2. Initially, you leave the matrix mode as `GL_PROJECTION` in `myInit()`

These two together mean that for the first frame, you just use identity as `MODELVIEW` matrix, and just overwrite the projection matrix twice. After a resize, the frame ais drawn again, and your code does waht you probably intented to do.

However, there is more:

3. You do not have any resize handler, so your viewport will not change when you resize the window.
4. You are setting an ortho matrix initailly for the projection, although you are not planning to use it at all.

and, the most import point:

5. All of your code depends on *deprecated* functionality which is *not even available in modern OpenGL at all*. You should really not use this in 2016, but learn modern OpenGL instead (with "modern" meaning "only a decade old" here).

Comment: Thanks @derhass for your suggesstion it work i will surely follow modern Open gl <3